# What is the address of buf (the local variable in the main function)?

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, memory-address

I had exercise from programming in C classes and I had followed question:

What is the address of buf (the local variable in the main function)? Enter the answer in either hexadecimal format (a 0x followed by 8 “digits” 0–9 or a-f, like 0xbfff0014) or decimal format. Note here that we want the address of buf, not its contents.

the code looks like follow:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   while(1) {
       char  buf[1024] = {0};
       int r;
    ....
```

So I ran `gdb` and simply put breakpoint at `char buf[1024]` line and typed in `gdb`

```
 p &buf
```

and that give me a result: 0xbffff0f0

but when I use this number in this quiz it give me result that this value is incorrect.

My question is: is this (p &buf) adress of buf variable?  Or if no why not?

Exercises are made on VirtualBox prepared machine so I think that everyone should have the same addresses

Comment: Yes, that is the address of `buf`. No, that address isn't guaranteed to be `0xbffff0f0` (it can be different on different computers; heck, it could even be different for different runs of the program on the same computer!). If you had a quiz asking you that question, there are likely more constraints or assumptions from the quiz that you aren't stating.

Comment: Yes, `p` prints an expression, and `&buf` is the expression of the buffer. And whoever made that quiz is a moron (unless they nailed everything down hard and used a deterministic implementation), because what exactly that address will be is far too fragile for a quiz. It can change literally at the drop of a hat.

Comment: buf is already a pointer. you are taking its address. Use p buf in gdb instead.

Comment: @JewelThief: **no**, `buf` is an array, **not** a pointer.

Comment: yes my bad. buf is pointing to first element of array.

Comment: @JewelThief: An array decays to a pointer to its first element in most contexts (know where it does not!). And we are not masochistic or sadistic when nitpicking like that, its essential to understanding  what's what, and to avoid false generalizations. Sloppy nomenclature and coding leads to bad bugs.

Comment: @JewelThief: `&buf` is *not* the address of a pointer object. It is the address of an array object. There is no pointer object (other than `argv`) in the program. `&buf` is the address of the array object. `buf` (*unless* it's the operand of unary `&` or `sizeof`) is the address of the array object's zeroth element; it's the same memory address, but is of type `char*` rather than `char(*)[1024]`.

Comment: gdb disables ASLR by default, so the address ought to be consistent on each run given the *identical* run-time environment each time (including exported shell variables and their values, name of the program, and any arguments or input values), but without seeing more of the code and the way you compiled it, named it, and ran it, it's hard to pinpoint why the value printed by `gdb` might differ from what your teacher expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a correct numerical answer. The address might vary from one time to another. It's a programming exercise you say. The following three statements all gave the same address for me.

```
printf ("0x%08x\n", buf);
printf ("0x%08x\n", &buf[0]);
printf ("0x%08x\n", &buf);
```

Comment: Of course they all give the same address. They will always give the same address (within a single run). They might differ across multiple runs, but within one run they will all be the same.

Comment: On a 64 bit compiler, 8 hex digits are not enough to print an address.

Comment: @Cornstalks wrote "Of course they all give the same address." You know that, I know that, but does the student?

Comment: "The following three statements all gave the same address for me." makes it sound like "This is the behavior I observe; others might observe different behavior" (it's the "for me" part at the end that slightly twists the statement to be misleading).

Comment: @Cornstalks first you repeated my answer, and then you challenged it. Sorry, not playing. I wrote it the way I did, because although it works - for me - it is not necessarily correct. I was encouraging OP to experiment, which is what learning is all about.

Comment: But the case is that each run should be made on the same enviroment: prepared Virtual Box image of linux system

Comment: @WeatherVane: That's what I'm nit-picking. It *is* correct. It's not just "for me." It's not hand wavy magic. `buf == &buf == &buf[0]`, always. Every time. For everyone.

Comment: Not according to @2501

Comment: @Cornstalks  I'm curious. Could you point out where in the Standard is that guaranteed? You can post an answer with that, if it is correct I'll upvote it.

Comment: @five555 perhaps adding the breakpoint realigned the compiled code to give the 'wrong' answer, but perhaps using one of the statements I suggest does not. Experiment with one of them, see if you get a different answer.

Comment: @2501: it's implied in 6.5.2.1 ("`E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`", which means `buf[0]` is identical to `*(buf + 0)`, which is identical to `*buf`. Further, 6.2.5/20 requires arrays to be contiguous. 6.5.(6 and 9)/7 says that `int* p;` acts the same as `int p[1];`. 6.5.9/6 says "Two pointers compare equal if [...] both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning)" (which would mean `&buf == &(buf[0])`). I think those all tightly constrain the behavior we've mentioned.

Comment: @Cornstalks `&buf == buf` cannot even be evaluated since the types are not the same. Standard doesn't define comparison between incompatible types. On a modern system, if you walk trough the bytes of both &buf and buf and compare them, the values will probably be the same, but Standard doesn't guarantee that, since incompatible types don't have to have the same size or alignment. I'm ending this discussion, but I encourage you to ask a question about it if  i didn't convince you.

Comment: @2501: They're incompatible types, sure, but you could cast them both to `char*` and compare those.

Comment: The correct way to print a pointer value is to use the `%p` format. That format requires a `void*` argument, so the argument should be cast: `printf("%p\n", (void*)buf);` Omitting the cast is likely to work, but it could fail on some exotic systems. `%x` requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. Using `%x` (or `0x%08x`) with a pointer argument has undefined behavior, and is likely to fail on systems where pointers are not the same size as `unsigned int` (such as the system I'm typing this on).